# How to recover total hours when cell has been marked as a date time type

Tags: excel

I have a excel workbook where a column that was supposed to show total hours logged in by the employee was marked as a date time column.
So, lets say an employee logged 373:15:18 hours (what's seen in the cell), when i highlight the cell it shows "1/15/1900  1:15:18 PM".

Copy pasting the values from that column to another column and marking it as a general column or text converts the numbers to all sorts of things. How can I extract the values that are shown (the total hours logged - 373:15:18)?

Comment: The time is a number format.  When you extract the value you are extracting the number behind the format.  If you want to keep the format then you need to paste the format with the paste of the value or, re format the target cell to be the same format as the original cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract 1/1/1900 12:00am from that value to get the duration.

At worst, you'll end up with a number of seconds and can do the math to get Hours and Minutes.

Comment: Awesome! Worked perfectly.

Comment: caught an error - if i use the difference, when the number of employee hours goes before 24.00 (since 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM is 24:00), i get error (##########)

Comment: Forget DateDif...my original math-based answer seems to work better:
=(H11-DATE(1900,1,1)) * 24 results in 349.26 hours.  I'm not sure how you're getting 373 hours.

Comment: Hey Steve, I just multiplied the datetime cell with 24 and got the correct hours. Thank you for putting me on the right track!